# how do i use subquery in db_api condition?

Tags: database

I am using drupal 7 and i would like to create subquery in condition clause with db_api. With db_query it goes something like this:

```
select *
from some_table_1
where some_table_1.something =
 (select max(some_table_2.something)
  from some_table_2
  where some_table_1.id = some_table_2.id
);
```

Among other, I was trying it with

```
$query->condition('some_table_1.something', $subquery);
```

and i cant get it to work.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you properly you need to use a standard where clause rather than a condition in your sub query, e.g.

```
$subquery = db_select('some_table_2');
$subquery->where('some_table_1.id = some_table_2.id');

...

$query->condition('some_table_1.something', $subquery);
```

Comment: The operator is not the problem, but connection table from outside the subquery and inside it.  where some_table_1.id = some_table_2.id

Comment: Gotcha, try the edit

Comment: Sorry, but addExpression adds code in "select" part of the clause, not "where".. so i get: SELECT some_table_1.id = some_table_2.id AS expression, MAX(some_table_2.something)

Comment: My apologies, it's early ;) you need the `where()` function instead

Comment: It works! Thanks! i was on my way to try join everything.. it would be a nightmare:)

Comment: @user13359 Actually Joins are better than nested select statements, the query in question is a slow query, you will notice that when there are more than thousand records in those tables.

Comment: I expect no more than 5 records available in subquery. From this 5, i need max(). I didn't expect it to be very slow, would it?

Comment: @user13359 Slower than the equivalent JOIN'd query, yes. Aggregating over a subquery will probably always be slower than a query that has defined routes as it were

Comment: You learn something every day:)